# Trouble with SqlParser using Anorm

Tags: scala, anorm

I'm trying to parse some SQL and save it as PushMessage (which is a class, not a case class - don't know if that matters). Following the Anorm documentation I have

```
 implicit val parser: RowParser[PushMessage] = Macro.namedParser[PushMessage]

  val result = db.withConnection { implicit connection: Connection =>

    SQL"select * from PUSH_MESSAGES where VENDOR_ID=$requestedVendorId;".as(parser.*)
  }
```

However, I'm getting a problem as IntelliJ tells me that Macro.namedParser[PushMessage] returns an Any, and not a RowParser[PushMessage]. I tried removing the declaration type, but then I couldn't run the parser using the `.as(parser.*)` syntax.

How do I get this to return a RowParser?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Have you tried compiling directly? IntelliJ doesn't always play well with macros and might be telling you something is wrong when it isn't actually..

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are using an Anorm version before 2.5.1 (April 2016), when the macros have been updated to use [whitebox context](https://github.com/playframework/anorm/commit/abd92242694b67c1644e72068d7c76f68cd4e58f). In such case, your IDE cannot properly infer the return type.

> Note that [Anorm 2.5.2 has just been released](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/play/anorm_2.11/2.5.2/anorm_2.11-2.5.2.pom).

Comment: Thanks for that precision! It save me a lot of time!